# What TCP ports are used for Azure DevOps Artifacts Universal Packages?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, artifacts, azure-artifacts

As the questions says:  What port number does the Azure DevOps task "Universal packages" use to communicate back to Azure DevOps Artifacts in order to fetch packages down?  In the company I have requested them to white-list ports # 80 & 443 for IP addresses:

```
13.107.6.0/24
13.107.9.0/24
13.107.42.0/24
13.107.43.0/24
```

By policy, I cannot just tell them to open all the ports.  So I have to be selective.  The task uses the executable "ArtifactTool.exe".  The agents are working fine and tasks are being downloaded.  I know I can set the proxy in Internet Options, but since this is a Production server I cannot set the proxy for server-wide since it will impact other production services.

Answer (score 0):

All Universal Packages operations are conducted over plain HTTPS. Only port 443 is required.

As an aside, the existence, interface, and functionality of ArtifactTool.exe is an internal implementation detail and should not be relied upon directly.

Comment: After more research and this link https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/3801 I think I found a source of IP addresses depending on our ADO Organization, which in the SOUTH CENTRAL US.  The latest Azure IP Addresses can be found here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=41653 by Region Name.  I don't know if this is the solution, but I'm going to submit 190 ip address for firewall rules and we'll see if it works.